# Why won't this code work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, cross-browser

I'm trying to prevent the onmouseout event from firing when the mouse moves from an outer div in to one of the container's child elements.  Here's the solution I came up with.  It works in IE8 and Chrome, but not in Firefox (latest version).  This is because in the Foo function, window.event is null.  I've also verified no arguments get passed into the function.  How do I make this code work in Firefox?

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="background-color: blue; width: 400px; height: 400px;" onmouseout="Foo()" id="Outer">
   <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;" id="Inner">
      Child element
   </div>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
   var outer = document.getElementById('Outer');

   function Foo()
   {
      var toElem = event.relatedTarget || event.toElement;

      if(toElem != outer.parentNode)
         return;

      window.alert('Outer div fired onmouseout..');
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why dont you install the major browsers on your pc and test it? Thats how i do it, IE, Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera

Comment: Why don't you just test with each of the major browsers? You're only missing FF, Safari and Chrome. Anyways, using jQuery you basicly have a working script in any browser (IN MOST CASES)

Comment: Great site for checking browser compatibility of DOM events (also, CSS properties): http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Comment: +1 for jQuery or other library, you probably can't get better cross-browser support..

Comment: +1 for wanting to find solutions on your own (without hiding behind jQuery). -1 for asking StackOverflow to do the basic testing you should be doing. Try it out. If it doesn't work, try to find a solution. If you get stuck, ask a question.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks at first glance that your code should work fine in IE, but other browsers may have an issue with the use of the `toElement` property of the event object, which is a IE-specific property. The W3C defined property is called `relatedTarget`. So you should probably do a check to see which to use:

```
var toElem = event.relatedTarget || event.toElement;
if(toElem != outer.parentNode) {
   //Do stuff
}
```

Note - I haven't actually tried your code in all browsers, so there may be other issues, but this is the one that leapt out at me.

Comment: Also `event` is being read from the non-standard global (`window.event`) which won't work on anything but IE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this doesn't work on Firefox.  I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Since you're using an inline handler, if you do `onmouseout="Foo(event)"`, then make your function's signature `function Foo(event) {...`, the intermediate function that invokes your `"Foo(event)"` will pick up the event object in both IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  This code works in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="background-color: blue; width: 400px; height: 400px;" id="Outer">
   <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;" id="Inner">
      Child element
   </div>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
   var outer = document.getElementById('Outer');

   outer.onmouseout = function Foo(args)
   {
      var toElem = (window.event) ? (event.relatedTarget || event.toElement) : args.relatedTarget;

      if(toElem != outer.parentNode)
         return;

      window.alert('Outer div fired onmouseout..');
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool. tell people what was wrong with it, an accept your answer.

Comment: There were a few problems.  1) The "args" parameter doesn't get sent into the Foo funtion if you bind the event handler declaratively.  2) window.event doesn't exist in Firefox, so using event.relatedTarget causes Firefox to silently fail and not evaluate the rest of the expression - thus you have to check for the existence of window.event before you do anything.  As mentioned before, jQuery will abstract all of these things and make event binding much easier.  YUI also provides similar benefits with its `Event.addListener()` API.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't allow you to accept your own answer (nor will you get any "points" for it anyway) for 2 days, so I decided to accept the first answer, as I found it helpful and it got me pointed in the right direction.